# Mount services into caddy with directories

Tags: reverse-proxy, caddy

I want to host a few services (currently cal/carddav, synthing and popfile) on my local pc and share them to the local network without having to care for ports. I am using Caddy as a reverse proxy.

So, I'd like localhost:5232 to be accessible as https://myhostname.local/radicale and similar mappings for the other services.
However `sudo caddy reverse-proxy --from myhostname.local/radicale --to localhost:5232` gives `reverse-proxy: paths are not allowed: myhostname.local/radicale`.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

The `caddy reverse proxy` command is very limited and doesn't work with paths. To use paths you would need to setup a caddyfile similar to the one below. You'll need to repeat the second line changing the path and port for each service.

Filename: `caddyfile`

```
myhostname.local
reverse_proxy /radicale localhost:5232
```

From now on start caddy with `sudo caddy start`